# Velocity from Accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, kalman-filter

I came to the conclusion that it is impossible to determine the velocity given the accelerometer in an android device. Assuming my initial velocity to be zero the integration schema employed to get the velocity would be

```
v_ib_b = old_v_ib_b + f_ib_b * dt ,
```

where v_ib_b is the velocity in the inertial body frame resolved along the body axes and f_ib_b is the measured force by the accelerometer.
If I want to compute the velocity of the smartphone in the local navigation frame ENU the following formula can be used (simplified Bortz equation neglecting coriolis/sculling and transport rate):

```
v_eb_n = old_v_eb_n + (C_b_n * (f_ib_b + 0.5 * cross(omega_ib_b, f_ib_b)) - g) * dt
```

where C_b_n is the rotation matrix body to ENU.
I attempted to use the `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`, MadgwickAHRS and my own sensor fusion to obtain the orientation and hence the rotation matrix in the ENU frame, respectively. No matter which one was used this is an ouput of integrating the velocity over a few minutes while riding with a bike (smartphone was mounted to the handlebar facing sky):
[image]

and this is the raw data integrated:
[image]

I assume the accelerometer to perform poor, being noisy and cancel out any measurements over time hence not being able to obtain the velocity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The relatively very small changes in acceleration will be mixed in with the noise.   Is something blocking the use of the GPS data?  Another direction would be combining the gyroscope data with the accelerometer data for better noise reduction, creating a full IMU.

Comment: What do you mean by combining gyroscope with accelerometer? If your are speaking of sensor fusion I already did that to obtain the orientation.